# Showing / hiding of divs containing repeaters not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm attempting to show one div containing a slideshow and hide another containing a list of images generated on larger screens i.e desktops. And do the opposite on smaller screens. Both Div's contain repeater controls, not sure if that interferes in any way but I do not think it does. Not sure why it's not working any suggestions would be very appreciated.

My jQuery and the CSS classes it attempts to implement;

```
$(function () {
        $(window).resize(function () { ToggleSlideshow(); });
        ToggleSlideshow();
    });

    function ToggleSlideshow() {
        // Apply your condition here to toggle the visibility of the slide show
        if ($(window).width() < 500) {
            $("#slideShowContainer").addClass(".hiding");
        $("#imgList").addClass(".showing");
    } else {
            $("#slideShowContainer").addClass(".showing");
    $("#imgList").addClass(".hiding");
    }
    }

.showing{
display:block;
}
.hiding{
display:none;
}
```

When I say it's not working, what I mean is both are being displayed which is not what I am trying to achieve. To see it live please follow [this link](http://www.griffithswebdesign.com/TreeTopsCarpentry/Portfolio).

Comment: Note: you never remove either class, just add it, whats happening then depends on the order of the class definitions. Further note that the resize event might be fired multiple times within a short time intervall, when resizing via the handles, this might cause unwanted behaviour (serach for "throttling").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working in the end. I did as follows:

```
  $(function () {
  $(window).resize(function () { ToggleSlideshow(); });
  ToggleSlideshow();
});

function ToggleSlideshow() {
  // Show your slideshow on widths larger than 500, otherwise show your list of images
  $("#<%=slideShowContainer.ClientID%>").toggle($(window).width() >= 660);
  $("#<%=imgList.ClientID%>").toggle($(window).width() < 660);
}
```